# Get index of components in slots in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, slot

Lets say I have

```
  <tabs>
    <tab :title="'tab 1'">tab content1</tab>
    <tab :title="'tab 2'">tab content2</tab>
  </tabs>
```

in tabs.vue i have

```
<template>
  <section :class="mode ? 'tabs--light' : 'tabs--dark'" @change-tab="selectTab(2)">
    <slot></slot>
  </section>
</template>
```

how do I know index in single `tab.vue`? I'm passing `tab` into tabs slot so I dont know how many `<tab>` are within `<tabs>`. How I can establish in each tab.vue which is its index meaning which order it has? In above case first  would have 0 and second  would have 1.

Do i need to pass a prop to each like this?

```
  <tabs>
    <tab :title="'tab 1' :id='0'>tab content1</tab>
    <tab :title="'tab 2' :id='1'>tab content2</tab>
  </tabs>
```

Comment: I think you are going to need to use a render function to do this.  Here is a link to an example.  https://forum.vuejs.org/t/loop-with-v-for-slots-default/20646/11

Comment: Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68909461/381282) - it is about carousel component but scenario is very similar and I'm pretty sure solution will help you...